# Does Symfony fetch the entire object from database when passing it to Twig?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to optimize my Symfony project and wondering if an entity object is being fully (all fields) fetched from the database when I pass it to a Twig template from a controller or only the fields that are being used in templates?

Let's say I have a `book` entity that has `title` and `abstract` fields. In a controller I fetch all the `book`s from the respective repository:

```
$books = $booksRepository->findAll();
```

and then pass it to a Twig template:

```
return $this->render('books.html.twig', [
    'books' => $books
]);
```

Afterwards, in `books.html.twig` I iterate through the `books` object but using the `title` field only:

```
{% for book in books %}
    Title: {{ book.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

I wonder if the `abstract` field is also being read by Symfony from the database. Of course, it's an example and production projects may have entities with more fields. Therefore, I assume fetching unused fields on certain webpages may cause extra load to the app and database. And if the answer to my initial question is positive, I'm also curious about techniques that are used to avoid fetching unused fields.

I tried to debug the Symfony and Doctrine classes, but eventually got lost in number of classes used and couldn't find an answer to my question.

Comment: In short, unless you've specified `SELECT` columns, yes... all fields are retrieved from the DB. The real question is why you think this might be an issue

Comment: It's Doctrine that does this sort of thing.  It is worthwhile reading the Doctrine docs.  Doctrine supports what they call `partials` in which you specify which columns you want but they can be tricky since the entities are not fully hydrated and fun things can happen if you do try to access the uninitialized columns.  Otherwise yes all the mapped columns will be fetched.  But once again, read through some of the docs.  They contain sections on what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: As soon as you do `$books = $booksRepository->findAll();` All data from books are called from database by Doctrine, and all books are hydrated. If you have a lot of books on your database, a lot of memory will be used by PHP/Doctrine. If you want to avoid it: do not load all books (cut and slice) or if you need all of them in your response, you can use partials as @Cerad suggests it. In any case, you could use a dedicated cache layer before the twig rendering to populate an array of titles instead of providing all hydrated books. Stores the titles and avoid calls to findAll() method.

Comment: Thank you, your answers clarify many aspects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is not related to Symfony or Twig.
It is related to Doctrine 2 and the way you made your code inside Repositories.

When using `$books = $booksRepository->findAll();` it will always fetch all fields.
It will be the same with all native doctrine function

```
find()
findOneBy()
findAll()
findBy()
```

If you want only a subset of field you will have to make custom repository function.
For example :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('book')->select('book.id, book.title, book.author');
```

And call it instead of your findAll().

But personnally, i do not totally agree with

> I assume fetching unused fields on certain webpages may cause extra
> load

You have to look to absolute gain value in term of ms. Most of the time for "little" entity, your query will gain 0.000xxx ms for querying only a subset of field.
So i advise you to not automatically create custom repository method since load / time gain are often irrelevant and do it only when bad performance occur. It will prevent you to create a lot of code that will need to be maintain in the futur.
Don't stick to a religion haha